# Meteor check object is instance of class

Tags: meteor

In [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns) for matching pattern of `check(value, pattern)`, it was mentioned:

```
Any constructor function (eg, Date)
    Matches any element that is an instance of that type.
```

meaning that I can test if the value is actually an instance of my own class.

The pattern is correctly using my class constructor function as the pattern but the match failed although I am passing a class instance, something like:

```
check(new EventObject(param1, param2), EventObject);
```

where `EventObject` is my own class.

Did I do something wrong? Is there another way to use `check()` to check for class instance or should I just use my own check with `instanceof`?

Comment: Found the [relevant piece of code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/check/match.js#L278). Seems to work fine for me.. (but I only tested this block of code!)

Comment: By `class constructor function` do you mean ES2015-style class constructor?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I found out that the type of the object was lost when I call `Meteor.call('collection.insert', eventObject)`. Inside `Meteor.methods`, `eventObject instanceof EventObject` becomes `false`.

Comment: That is strange. I'll try to test it as well.

Comment: Yes, I checked it out. The `constructor` is lost when object is called sent as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tested on Meteor 3.0 (3.1 was not out then), using `check`on an object constructed using ES2015-style class constructor will not work as the type of the object is lost on calling `Meteor.call('collection.insert', eventObject)`.

This can be tested by seeing that `eventObject instanceof EventObject` evaluates to `false` in `Meteor.methods`.